# MongoDB .find works in shell but not in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm very new to Node Express Mongo so after following a few tutorials I wanted to try to rewrite my own baby site. This is a `login` page. Other people's code works for me but when I tried it my way didn't work. I've also consulted the documentation, they do stuff like `db.bios.find( { _id: 5 } )` which is what I've tried to mimic

db is `ShipDB`, collection is `users`, document I'm trying to find is

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56edc18064e429581541808a"),
        "username" : "username",
        "password" : "password"
}
```

Below, I am connecting and if `result.length` then redirect to home page. I've tried entering `username` and `password` on the website correctly but it says invalid login. `console.log(result.length)` prints out undefined? Why is that? Here is logcat:

```
Connection established successfully
undefined
{ username: 'username', password: 'password' }



router.post('/validate', function(req, res) {
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"+database_name;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       if(!err) {
           console.log("Connection established successfully");
           var user_collection = db.collection(collection_name_users);
           var user_login_input = {
               username: req.body.username,
               password: req.body.password
           };
           // THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT I HAVE A PROBLEM WITH!!!!
           user_collection.find(
               {
                   username: req.body.username,
                   password: req.body.password
               }, function(err, result) {
                   if(!err) {
                       console.log(result.length);
                       if (result.length) {
                           // Successful login
                           req.session.user = result;
                           delete req.session.user.password;
                           res.redirect("home");
                       } else {
                           console.log(user_login_input);
                           res.send("Invalid login");
                       }

                       db.close();
                   } else {
                       console.log(err);
                   }
           });

       } else {
           console.log("Cannot connect ", err);
       }
    });

});
```

Things I've tried:

- `user_collection.find(user_login_input, function(err, result) {...`
- `user_collection.find({ "username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password })...`
- Works on mongoshell:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: findOne looks deprecated

[image]

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks for the link! Sorry for the dupe. I had known of findOne but I heard it was deprecated, not sure of the difference. Either way, the link helped

Comment: Glad it helped. `findOne` is definitely not deprectated; where did you hear that?

Comment: @JohnnyHK My IDE IntelliJ Idea, it definitely could be wrong though. I edited my question to include a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the node.js got the same result as the mongo shell, but the `result` is not an array, and `result.length` is `undefined`. What you can do is check if `result` is an array or an object first.

The line `console.log(user_login_input);` gave the right output `{ username: 'username', password: 'password' }`.